# How to round my average and remove the brackets in my output?

Tags: python, rounding

I have a program with an output, but I want the output to be clean (so with no brackets or quotation marks) and I want to numbers to be rounded to 2 decimals.

I tried to use the round function and I tried to use the .join method for the brackets, but none of them work.

```
import csv
import locale
from pprint import pprint, pformat

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Dutch_Netherlands.1252')

gem_names = 'sellerRating', 'Duration', 'ClosePrice', 'OpenPrice'
gemiddelde = {gem_name: 0 for gem_name in gem_names}  # Zet de totale op nul.

num_waarden = 0
with open('bijlage.txt', newline='') as bestand:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(bestand, delimiter=';')
    for row in csvreader:
        for gem_name in gem_names:
            gemiddelde[gem_name] += locale.atof(row[gem_name])
            num_waarden += 1

for gem_name, total in gemiddelde.items():
    gemiddelde[gem_name] = gemiddelde[gem_name] / num_waarden

print ('Dit zijn de gemiddelden:')
pprint(gemiddelde)
```

This is the output I got:

```
Dit zijn de gemiddelden:
{'ClosePrice': 9.712094266277953,
 'Duration': 1.6350826044703595,
 'OpenPrice': 3.553561710398435,
 'sellerRating': 940.226433430515}
```

I got an error with trying the `round(gemiddelde)`. When I tried to use the `.join` my numbers dissapeared. Can anyone help me to make this look clean?

Comment: change `gemiddelde[gem_name] += locale.atof(row[gem_name])` to `gemiddelde[gem_name] += round(locale.atof(row[gem_name]),2)` will solve your problem.

Comment: This does not work. I do not know why.

Comment: change `gemiddelde[gem_name] = gemiddelde[gem_name] / num_waarden`  to `gemiddelde[gem_name] = round(gemiddelde[gem_name] / num_waarden, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Better not `round` during the calculations, as the rounding error might add up. Instead, just use a loop and a format string for printing the values instead of relying on `pprint`, for example:

```
>>> gemiddelte = {'ClosePrice': 9.712094266277953, 'Duration': 1.6350826044703595, 'OpenPrice': 3.553561710398435, 'sellerRating': 940.226433430515}
>>> for key, val in gemiddelte.items():
...     print("%15s  %6.2f" % (key, val))
...
     ClosePrice    9.71
       Duration    1.64
      OpenPrice    3.55
   sellerRating  940.23
```

Or similar, using `str.format`:

```
>>> for key, val in gemiddelte.items():
...     print("{0:<15} {1:6.2f}".format(key, val))
...
ClosePrice        9.71
Duration          1.64
OpenPrice         3.55
sellerRating    940.23
```

Comment: But if I edit something in my txt the average is not correct anymore. That is needed in my program.

Comment: @JosseLardinois Of course you should still get the values in `gemiddelte` from your text file, I just added the dict as a literal from your example output for testing.

Comment: So if I change some value in my text file, my average will change automaticly too?

Comment: @JosseLardinois No, if you change values in your file, of course you have to read the file again using the code from your question. I thought that part was clear.